# trying to assign dataframe rows to a list of words(Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

im new to python and need your help.
basically im having a list of strings and a dataframe calles df and im trying to assign each language to a seperate df based on a condition.
it looks like:

```
languages = ['JavaScript', 'HTML/CSS', 'SQL', 'Python', 'Bash/Shell/PowerShell', 'Java']
for language in languages:
   language = df[df['LanguageWorkedWith'].str.contains('language')]
```

I want each language to be assigned to a dataframe based on the condition, instead of assigning every language seperately like:
Python = df[df['LanguageWorkedWith'].str.contains('Python')]
etc...

how do i run the loop so each word in languages assign to a dataframe based on it's name?

Comment: add expected output

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you're trying to turn the list languages into a pandas dataframe?

If so here is the code for that:

`languages = ['JavaScript', 'HTML/CSS', 'SQL', 'Python', 'Bash/Shell/PowerShell', 'Java']
df = pd.Dataframe(languages)`

But as commented above if you write your expected output it would help!

Comment: hi thank you for your answer, i edited my question to be more specific